# Spotify - access token from command line

Tags: python, command-line, spotify, spotipy

I am testing my `app` using the `terminal`, which is quite handy in a pre-development phase.

so far, I have used `spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)` within my `python` scripts in order to access data.

`SpotifyClientCredentials()` requires `client_id`and `client_secret` as parameters.

now I need to access `analysis_url` data, which requires an `access token`.

Is there a way to include this `access token` requirement via my `python` script ran at `command line` or do I have to build an `app` on the `browser` just to do a simple test?

many thanks on advance.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the entire redirect URI from your browser to the terminal (when prompted) after successful authentication.  Your access token will be cached in the directory (look for `.cache.<username>`)